# How to solve: $\int \frac{1}{36x^2(1+12x)^2}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I was given the following problem: $$\displaystyle\int \frac{1}{36x^2(1+12x)^2}\mathrm dx$$ I was told to solve it using the following formula from an integral table: $$\int\frac{\mathrm du}{u^2(a+bu)^2}=-\frac1{a^2}\left[\frac{a+2bu}{u(a+bu)}+\frac{2b}a\ln\left|\frac{u}{a+bu}\right|\right]+C$$
I am not sure how to plug this in. I do see that you can pull $\frac1{36}$ out of the problem, and that we have $x^2$ and $(1+12x)^2$ in the denominator, but what do we need to set as our variables?

Comment: you could always use the "brute force approach" by noting that the denominator has 2 real roots, both of them of multiplicity 2. Since they're real, you can try the partial fractions method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u=6x$. Then $u^2 = 36x^2$, $2u=12x$, and $du=6 \;dx$. Your integral becomes

$$\int \frac{1}{36x^2(1+12x)^2}dx = \int \frac{1}{u^2(1+2u)^2}\cdot \frac 1 6 \; du$$

You can solve it from here using your formula.

Answer (score -3):

Hint

Express the numerator as $$(12x+1-12x)^2=(12x+1)^2+(12x)^2-24x(12x+1)$$

Again $$\dfrac1{x(12x+1)}=\dfrac{12x+1-12x}{x(12x+1)}=?$$

Comment: Please pinpoint the mistake which has invited so many downvotes?

Comment: (Not a downvoter) The denominator from the OP is not copied correctly, at least, it is $36x^2 (1+12x)^2$ not $x(12x+1)$.